# how to add/delete record in elastic search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, indexing, elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch as data store in my rails application
how can I add/delete record(row) and maintain indexes.Ii go through the ES-docs

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

adding record is looks lengthiest here

Is there any other feasible way to do so..

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem https://github.com/karmi/retire allowed interacting with Elasticsearch

Comment: I am using same!!but using ES as db by making the bunch of data in csv file and import it but what will i need to do when more record added/delete should i maintain csv file and make the rake db:seed

Comment: then you may put some callback to your ActiveRecord model and only in case when appropriated attributes changed then send data to elasticsearch. This is how we use the Elasticsearch in our application. CSV files can be used when you make an initial data import

Answer (score 0):

You can use rivers plug-ins.. It Ll take care of insert, update, delete, operation of documents..  You need to map ES To dB and send search request to ES server.

Note: choose river plug in according to your DB..